# Message only being passed with fgets in named pipe

Tags: c

Server.c

```c
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {

    mkfifo("/tmp/fifox", 0666);
    char message[50];

    for(;;) {
      int fd = open("/tmp/fifox", O_RDONLY);
      read(fd, message, 50);
      printf("%s", message);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Client.c

```c
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {

    int fd = open("/tmp/fifox", O_WRONLY);
    char message[50];
    scanf("%s", message);
    //fgets(message, 50, stdin);

    write(fd, message, 50);
    close(fd);

    return 0;
}
```

Whenever I try to pass from client message with `scanf` then it's not being received on my server. Same thing happens whenever I do it like `char message[50] = "test"`. It only works when I write `fgets(message, 50, stdin);`

Comment: You're not checking the return values for **any** of your function calls to check if they succeeded or not, or how many bytes they've written or read...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probable cause is server side output issue. `fgets` includes a newline in the message, `scanf` does not.

Try this for printing the message:

```
printf("%s\n", message);
```

Or add `fflush(stdout);` after the `printf`.

---

Also, check return values of all input/read function calls! Also check return values of all output/write function calls, except "normal" printing to stdout or stderr (nobody checks those).